# JAVA | mybatis | Insert a multimap

Tags: java, insert, mybatis

I have a use-case wherein i want to insert a multimap ( eg. Multimap ) into database using mybatis.

i am not able to access key and value in mybatis using the following :
(assumed that it would invoke the entrySet and iterate on it internally before inserting)

```
INSERT INTO table1 (integer1, integer2)
VALUES (#{key} , #{value})
```

Any idea how this can be done ?
I am assuming there should be a straightforward way, as this is a basic use case.

--EDIT--

Though i can create a wrapper object, set these values and send them to mybatis, i wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve the end result without creating additional objects, as this is the only place where i need them.

Thanks for the help.

---EDIT---
Tested after incorporating the suggested solution.

Code snippet for details:

DAO layer:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("entries", myMultimap.entries());
```

Mybatis sql:

```
INSERT INTO table1
    (integer1, integer2)
VALUES
<foreach item="item" separator="," collection="entries">
   ( #{item.key} , #{item.value} )
</foreach>
```

--- EDIT ---

Guys, with the above solution watch out for max 2000 characters in parameter length. If you face the issue, batching/bulk insert will be the way to proceed further.

Comment: Doesn't a Multimap contain multiple values for a single key ? And multiple keys can have the same value. In that case (ManyToMany relationship) you can't model it in just one table.

Comment: why not, we can use a hashmultimap as the implementation and the table's key should include both integer1 and integer2. Then we can insert (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) , (2,1), (2,2), (2,3) without any issues. Let me know if i am missing something Jim.

Comment: An HashMultimap ensures there are no duplicate key-value pairs. But a single key can have `1..*` values. You could store that in a single table, but to reduce redudancy in your database model I'd advice using 2 tables: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 tables: KEYS and VALUES where VALUES should have a foreign key column referencing KEYS. Example:

```
TABLE KEYS:
| ID | KEY |
| 1  | key1| 

TABLE VALUES:
| ID | KEY_ID | VALUE |
| 1  | 1      | value1|
| 2  | 1      | value2|
```

Now to persist a multimap you need to first persist the a key in the KEYS table and then the corresponding values in the VALUES table. Let me know if you need an example of that.

**EDIT: See comments**

You should use the foreach tags in mybatis. Do a foreach on the keyset or on the entries.
Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (integer1, integer2)
VALUES 
<foreach item="item" seperator="," collection="#{entries}">
       ( #{item.key)},#{item.value})
    </foreach>
```

Where entries should reference the MultiMap.Entries()

Comment: In my example, integer1 is already a foreign key to another table and i dont see any advantage in using a surrogate key here.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot. Then indeed you should only have to use the VALUES able and omit the ID column. You need to loop over the values per key and insert that key value pair.

Comment: Exactly, so for that, i was wondering if i can pass the entire map to mybatis and let it take care of iterating and inserting every key-value pair

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim. I have updated the question with the tested solution.